# Python: how to reuse a base method while allowing in-method modifications?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, overriding

**Background**

I'm trying to implement the Black-Litterman model as a subclass of my already implemented [Markowitz model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_portfolio_theory). The main idea of Markowitz model is: you loop through a `date_list`, on each `date` you use the moving average approach to estimate the expected returns `mu` and the covariance matrix `sigma`, then you compute the mean-variance portfolio using the mean-variance optimiser `mean_variance(mu, sigma)`. Conceptually, the Markowitz model is like this

```
class Markowitz(object):
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.price_data = ...
        self.date_list = ...

    def estimate_mu_and_sigma(self, date):
        mu = ...
        sigma = ...
        return mu, sigma

    @staticmethod
    def mean_variance_optimiser(mu, sigma):
        w = ...
        return w

    def back_test(self):
        for date in self.date_list:
            mu, sigma = self.estimate_mu_and_sigma(date)
            w = Markowitz.mean_variance_optimiser(mu, sigma)

            # do some other stuff
            pass
```

The only difference between Black-Litterman and Markowitz is that BL uses a different estimate method for `mu` and `sigma` than Markowitz, but the subsequent mean-variance optimisation procedure is identical. Naturally I want to subclass `Markowitz` to get a BL model. The problem is that in BL, the estimates of `mu` and `sigma` need additional parameters. Not only that, but this set of additional parameters also depend dynamically on `date`, so I can't just override `Markowitz.back_test` to give it additional parameters. In fact, a BL model is like this:

```
class BlackLitterman(Markowitz):
    def __init__(self, params, more_parms):
        super().__init__(params)
        self.some_auxiliary_data = ...

    def estimate_mu_and_sigma(self, date, dynamic_params):
        mu = ...
        sigma = ...
        return mu, sigma


    def back_test(self, more_params):
        for date in self.date_list:
            dynamic_params = ...  # depends both on date and more params
            mu, sigma = self.estimate_mu_and_sigma(date, dynamic_params)
            w = Markowitz.mean_variance_optimiser(mu, sigma)

            # do some other stuff
            pass
```

When I try this, the IDE already complains about `BlackLitterman.estimate_mu_and_sigma` overriding `Markowtiz.estimate_mu_and_sigma` with inconsistent signature. Also, this doesn't actually reuse the reusable code in `back_test`.

Could anybody tell me how to more elegantly inherit from `Markowitz`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't actually try to make `Markowitz` your base class, but either have an abstract `Model` base class and implement both models as subclass, or - muc better IMHO for your use case - have one single `Model` concrete class that does everything except the `estimate_mu_and_sigma` and `mean_variance_optimiser`, and use the strategy pattern for those parts.

Strategy based solution:

```
class Estimator(object):
    def __init__(self, params, strategy):
        self.price_data = ...
        # etc
        self.strategy = strategy

    def back_test(self):
        for date in self.date_list:
            mu, sigma = self.strategy.estimate_mu_and_sigma(date)
            w = self.strategy.mean_variance_optimiser(mu, sigma)

            # do some other stuff
            pass


class MarkowitzStrategy(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
       # ...

    def estimate_mu_and_sigma(self, date):
        mu = ...
        sigma = ...
        return mu, sigma


class BlackLittermanStrategy(object):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
       # here you pass `more_params` and store them locally
       # etc so you can caculate 
       # `dynamic_params` here without polluting the Estimator class
       self.more_params = ....

    def _calc_dyn_params(self, date):
        return ...

    def estimate_mu_and_sigma(self, date):
        dynamic_params = self._calc_dyn_params(date)
        mu = ...
        sigma = ...
        return mu, sigma
```

Then you build the strategy with the appropriate arguments and pass it to your estimator. By splitting the variant part (the strategies) from the invariant (how to estimate), you avoid having to pollute the Estimator with irrelevant details.

NB: for the inheritance-based solution, you have to design your base class so it methods can accept all possible arguments for all possible estimation models, which is usually done using `*args` and `**kwargs` for all arguments that will vary from one concrete class to another. This doesn't really help wrt/ documentation and debugging...

Comment: Thanks. The `mean_variance_optimiser` is static so I assume it can be encapsulated in `Estimator`? Also, is double `def` a typo?

Comment: @Vim if `mean_variance_optimiser` (which I think should be named `optimize_mean_variance` - functions and methods are actions, so they should use verbs) is the same whatever the strategy then it doesn't have to be part of the strategy indeed - the fact you mentionned it in the BlackLitterman class led me to think it was overridden too.  And yes of course the `def def` thing is a typo ;-)

Comment: oops my bad. I shouldn't have mentioned it in BL. It's actually intended to inherit from Markowitz.